# SoapClient creating XML

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

I need to create this xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <soapenv:Header>  
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext">  
      <wsse:UsernameToken>  
        <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>  
        <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>  
      </wsse:UsernameToken>  
    </wsse:Security>  
  </soapenv:Header>  
  <soapenv:Body>  
    <vb:getAirportInfo xmlns:vb="http://www.example.com/schema/2005/02/booking.xsd">  
      <airport>BNE</airport>  
      <airport>PPP</airport>  
      <airport>MEL</airport>  
    </vb:getAirportInfo>  
  </soapenv:Body>  
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am new to using SoapClients and need some help doing this. How would I do it?

Comment: What language?  What platform?

Comment: I am using PHP and using SoapClient on an apache server

Comment: Have you tried something yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to do two things. 
First I needed to create the header section which had the security in it.
        $soap_client = new SoapClient("airportinfo.wsdl", array("trace" => 1,"exceptions"=>0));

```
    $header_part = '
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>'.$username.'</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>'.$password.'</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    ';
    $soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null );
    $soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'wsse', $soap_var_header, true );
    $soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);
```

Second I needed to create an array and pass it to the function that was the WSDL had. I got a list of these by using __getFunctions(). I then used this code to generate the last of the xml

```
    $airports = array("AirportInfoRQ" => array("AirportCode" => "PPP", "AirportCode" => "BNE"));
    $responce = $soap_client->AxisTransaction($airports);
```

This gave me slightly different xml I stated above but it was the correct xml to get the SoapClient working correctly

Answer (score 0):

To successfuly use SOAP from PHP, you need two things:

1. The first is SoapClient and/or SoapServer classes bundled with PHP. They work fine, see http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php for details.
2. The second is WsdlDocument library. It generates WSDL description of your services, so other clients can easily use it. See http://code.google.com/p/wsdldocument/

Using SoapClient is very simple, once you initialize it, you will get object on which you can call methods as usual and it will forward these calls to server.

SoapServer is only about creating instance of you service and calling handle method.

None of this includes manual handling of XML you posted. It *magically* works on it's own (quite literally).